# I train my model, and that is the result i get, is that good or not?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

*global step: 20
learning rate: 0.000100
training loss: 0.496505
validation accuracy: 0.130909*

this is my code:

```
 if ((step + 1) % FLAGS.display_freq) == 0:
            print(
                "[PROGRESS]: global step: %d | learning rate: %f | training_loss: %f | l2_loss: %f |val_accuracy %f" % (
                    results['global_step'], results['learning_rate'], results['training_loss'], results['l2_loss'],
                    val_acc))

        if ((step + 1) % FLAGS.save_freq) == 0:
            print('[INFO]: Save the checkpoint !!!!')
            # TODO: Check wehter result['global_step'] needs to be passed instead
            saver.save(sess, os.path.join(FLAGS.output_dir, 'model'), global_step=net.global_step)

    print('[INFO]: Optimization done!!!!!!!!!!!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    global step: 20 learning rate: 0.000100 training loss: 0.496505 validation accuracy: 0.130909
```

By looking at this it is clear that the validation accuracy is quiet less that means model might be over fitting as training accuracy is not shared here.

here the model performance is not good.if training accuracy is good and validation accuracy is bad then try any of the following.

You can

(1) Shuffle the Data

(2) Use Early Stopping

(3) Use Regularization

(4) You can try using Batch Normalization

(5) Perform Image Data Augmentation